# jquery add row to table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a new dynamically created row to add to a table but I can't. I found this example which has an add row and delete row feature. but it didn't work. Any idea why it wouldn't? Things look right over here...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test JS</title>  

<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript">
 <!-- jQuery Code will go underneath this -->
$('.add').live('click',function(){
    $(this).val('Delete');
    $(this).attr('class','del');

    var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td><td><input type="text" name="input_box_two[]" /></td><td><input class="add" type="button" value="Add More" /></td></tr>";
    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="options-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Input-Box-One</td>
            <td>Input-Box-Two</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
            <td><input class="del" type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
            <td><input class="add" type="button" value="Add More" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help, I need this working to avoid cluttering the interface...I know there are many examples in the forum here but none seem to be working. I also have jquery.js file in the same folder i have the .php file containing the same code shown above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using double quotes inside the **var appendTxt**.Change that double quotes to single quotes will work.

```
var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td><td><input class='add' type='button' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
```

Check this Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4LcgA/

Change ur code like this

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.add').live('click',function(){
    $(this).val('Delete');
    $(this).attr('class','del');
var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td><td><input class='add' type='button' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";

    $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);
});
</script>
```

Comment: it is working on the website you provided but not on mine. I copied it exactly into my file...any idea why?

Comment: @Gopesh yes I do have the latest jquery version...<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"> and this should work and is closed by another </script> and code is in between it. True, deleting row is not important

Comment: @sys_debug ok..Then press ctrl+shift+j for errors if u r using firefox

Comment: p.s. I wrote the above comment after changing the double quotes to single quotes in the var appendTxt. that's why I posted it still didn't work

Comment: nope...I don't know how to use the document.ready() here...and about the errors, there are none showing in the window when I pressed what you told me

Comment: @Gopesh I appreciate that too but still nothing happened...working on fiddle of course but not mine...

Comment: @sys_debug Try to close the <script> tag for jquery file.and open another <script> for ur jquery code..

Comment: @Gopesh genius! Thanks mate! that did it. don't know why though...any sensible explanation behind it? Thanks again :D

Comment: @sys_debug Welcome. the jquery src file and the code must be seperated with <script> tags.otherwise it will not recognize ur code or jquery

Answer (score 0):

use escape sequence \" when using quotes inside quotes!!!
try this,

```
 var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"input_box_one[]\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"input_box_two[]\" /></td><td><input class=\"add\" type=\"button\" value=\"Add More\" /></td></tr>";
```